# Please help me this function is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-writing, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

> Prove that $\dfrac {1} {x^2-2}$ is continuous.

I first did $\left|\dfrac {1} {x^2-2} - \dfrac {1} {x_0^2-2}\right|$. Then I combined into a single fraction and was able to separate it into

$$|x-x_0|\left(\frac {|x_0|} {(x^2-2)(x_0^2-2)}+\frac {|x|} {(x^2-2)(x_0^2-2)}\right)$$

However, I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: This function is not continuous over the whole real line. Do you want to check continuity at some $x_0 \in \Bbb R$?

Comment: Maybe "continuous" means continuous on its domain?

Comment: Maybe there was a typo in the question and instead it was supposed to say $x^2+2$?

Comment: Im not sure if it helps, but it says show f is continuous at x for all x in Q (rational numbers).

Comment: Then it suffices to show that $\sqrt2$ is irrational.

Comment: I'm curious about the background of the problem.  For example, have you already been taught that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions, then so are both $f \times g$ and $f\circ g$?  Further, have you been taught that if $f$ is a continuous function then for all $x_1$ such that $f(x_1) \neq 0,$ then $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is continuous at $x = x_1$?  Also, do you know how to use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) to prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is not a rational number?

Comment: @Jack:  You're new, so you don't know the etiquette.  But it is *essential* that you put clarifications to your question *WITHIN THE QUESTION* so that readers coming to your question will see it.

Comment: If you prove that all rational functions are continuous, then this applies. It's relatively easy to prove the aforementioned result